# How do I deploy a local charm from the Juju GUI?

Tags: juju

Is there a way to configure Juju GUI deploy local charm? I install vagrant/virtualbox local provider but doesn't see this feature either.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of the Juju GUI (cs:precise/juju-gui-85 at the time of writing) supports working with local charms.

It requires Juju version 1.17.3 or higher.

In order to work with local charms in the GUI you simply drag and drop a .zip archive of your charm onto the canvas portion of the GUI. You can even use this same procedure to upgrade already deployed charms with a local charm.

To deploy a local charm via the command line you would use the following command:

```
juju deploy --repository=/path/to/charm local:precise/charm-name
```

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/controllers-gui

Comment: Is there a way to make a local charm show in the browser?

Comment: I asked my question "how to show my local charms in the juju-gui charm browser" separately here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/646962/how-to-retrieve-and-list-local-charms-in-juju-gui-charm-browser.