# How to retrieve and list local charms in juju-gui charm browser?

Tags: juju

How do I get my local charms to be retrieved and listed in my environment's juju-gui "Charm Browser"?

According to the [documentation](http://jujucharms.com/precise/juju-gui) in the section titled "The Juju GUI server" item 7 "It supports deploying local charms.... **This also includes retrieving and listing local charms' files.**"

To be clear, I'm not asking how to deploy my charm, I need to test and demonstrate my charms starting from the "Charm Browser" as an end user would experience. Also, a set of charms will be created and tested in concert before publishing them to the store. So I need to see them end to end before considering publishing.

Other similar questions that did not answer my question include 
[How do I deploy a local charm from the Juju GUI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/409637/how-do-i-deploy-a-local-charm-from-the-juju-gui) and [How to locally add my charms to the juju-gui?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520432/how-to-locally-add-my-charms-to-the-juju-gui).

Comment: Also, there is a configuration property to set the URL to the store. Is there a way to change that to host our own store? That might work for my purposes. Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Comment: The wording on the Juju GUI readme is confusing. There is no way to list charms local to your own machine in the charm browser. I'll be sure to get that fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get your charms to show up in the charm browser you will need to push them to your own namespace in Launchpad. Less than 15 minutes later, assuming charm proof passes, you'll be able to see your own charm in there.

You can read about this process here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/authors-charm-store#submitting-a-new-charm

Just FYI, there is no technical difference between dragging from the Charm Browser and dragging a zip archive of your charm from your machine.

Comment: thanks for the fast response. I surmised as much but wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything. The issue for me is I don't want anyone to see what I'm doing until I'm ready to reveal it. And while technically the same the testing is not the same. I need to validate that the UI is doing what I need/want and when you show it prospects they don't get the same "feeling" when dragging a zip file.

Is there a feature request I can subscribe, too?

Comment: There hasn't been an issue created for this functionality yet, but if you'd like to make one to open up some discussion on the topic you can do so here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-gui

Comment: Per your suggestion, hatch, I created a feature request: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-gui/+bug/1474448.